# Cluster computer

Tags: networking, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I am trying to build a parallel processing computer.

I have

- 10 Windows7 64-bit machines
- 3 Ubuntu Linux machines
- 1 Windows 2008 server
- around 1km network cable
- 3-4 Switches

My need:

make my animation rendering faster by clustering these computers.

I am using 3Dmax for my project, and i am doing medical animations/videos. What is the best way to achieve this? I am not that good in networking, but all the basics, I know.

And one more question:

Suppose I build a cluster of Windows PCs, and if I connect a Linux machine to it, will that be any good?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is interesting but off-topic here.  However, some fragments of an answer:

These two books cover most of the topics necessary for building a home-brew (or even much more sophisticated) cluster out of a pile of PCs: [this one's for Linux](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beowulf-Computing-Scientific-Engineering-Computation/dp/0262692929/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1345011603&sr=1-2) and [this one's for Windows](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beowulf-Computing-Scientific-Engineering-Computation/dp/0262692759/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1345011708&sr=1-1).  They're both a bit out of date, which is probably more serious for the Window's version, but would give you a good coverage of the necessary topics.  Do some of your own research too, Google for topics such as *Beowulf clustering* and *Condor*; the latter is a system for scavenging spare cycles from networked computers.

I think heterogenous clusters, with machines having different OSes will be a little more difficult to build and configure than homogenous, but the degree of difficulty will be in proportion to the degree of integration you seek.

Your topic, rendering movie frames, falls into the class of *embarassingly parallel programs* and there are two general approaches:

- you simply pass frames one at a time to computers which work independently of each other; the difficulty (if there is any) comes in ensuring load-balancing, that is getting each computer to work as hard as every other computer.  This could look like a network of PCs independently reading frames from networked storage and scarcely like a cluster at all.
- you build a rendering pipeline: computer 1 does render operation 1 on frame 1, then passes the frame to computer 2 which does operation 2 on frame 1, while computer 1 starts render operation 1 on frame 2, and so on; again you have to give attention to keeping the pipeline full and busy.

Comment: Another consideration is latency.  In option 2--a pipeline--the latency is going to be the passing of data between each cluster node (computer in the cluster) plus sending the initial data and receiving the final data.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit late(7 years :D ) for thanking you for giving a good insight into the problem. But it did help me build the process. I used all windows based machines and made a  series processing unit and it still working fine. 

Thank you @High Performance Mark